# How to specify multiple dynamic attributes by single computed prop in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this html element:

```
<a href="javascript:">Link text</a>
```

I want to add `data-tooltip` and `title` attributes dynamically by condition:

```
<a href="javascript:" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text">Link text</a>
```

Is there any way in VueJS to add multiple dynamic attributes at same time:

```
<!-- instead of this: -->
<a href="javascript:" :data-toggle="computedPropTooltipToggle" :title="computedPropTooltipTitle">Link text</a>

<!-- something like this: -->
<a href="javascript:" ...tooltipAttributes >Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take advantage of `v-bind` on the DOM element you wish to apply multiple attributes to based on some dynamically changing condition.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6E21wK?p=preview) example demonstrating how you might go about it.

Take note of the object returned:

```
computed: {
  multiAttrs() {
    return this.showAttrs ? {
      'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
      title: 'Some tooltip text',
    } : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `v-bind="tooltipAttributes"`

the docs here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind have more info, but the key part is under usage

> Dynamically bind one **or more** attributes, or a component prop to an expression.

Comment: Perhaps ad some more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#dynamically-binding-multiple-attributes):

**1. You can dynamically bind multiple attributes/props to a single element by using `v-bind`:**

<sup>(no colon, no extra attribute, just `v-bind`)</sup>

```html
<a href="#" v-bind="tooltipAttributes" >Link text</a>
```

**2. And then declare the variable in the `computed` section:**

<sup>*(you can also declare it in the `data` section, but that would require manual direct value changes)*</sup>

```js
computed() {
  return {
    tooltipAttributes: {
      title: 'Title',
      'data-toggle': this.toggle === true && !disabled
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: Attributes with dashes/hyphens `-` in them (e.g. `data-toggle`) need to be a string because Javascript doesn't recognize `-` as a valid symbol in variable naming.</sup>

---

This is THE SAME AS:

```html
<a href="#" title="Title" :data-toggle="this.toggle === true && !disabled" >Link text</a>
```